# Transfer rows into a new table, forcing to generate unique primary keys till its insertable

Tags: mysql, innodb, insert, auto-increment

Lets say we have the following scenario...

```
+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
| Table           | PK          | Additional    |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
| playerinventory | id (int)    | amount, level |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
| newinventory    | id (BIGINT) | amount, level |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------+
```

We are in the middle of a architectural change of our game-database.

"amount, level" should get extracted from "playerinventory" and get **inserted into "newinventory"**.

***Limitations***

- "newinventory" has **no auto-increment pk**, therefore we need to
  generate a **unique long** for each... we also can not add
  "auto-increment" to the table
- "newinventory" could possible
  already contain those identities, so we need to check if the
  generated id already exists and if so **repeat the process** for the
  affected set of extracted columns **till it was inserted**
  successfully.
- We **CANT** simply insert each row from
  "playerinventory" into "newinventory" with its current id... that's
  simply not possible (if I would explain why this post would be much,
  much longer), that's why we **NEED** to generate a **new** unique
  **ID**

In nearly any programming language this process would look like this

```
for row in playerInventory
   id = generate new ID
   while(id in newInventory) id = generate new ID
   insert into newInventory( id, row.amount, row.level )
```

How can we achieve this in MySQL/SQL ?

The highest ID in "newinventory" is already 9223372036854775806 and therefore we cant increase anymore... we need to generate and test till it fits.

Comment: Are you saying that `newinventory` is already populated, and you won't want to re-do that? How many rows in the long run?  (I ask because `RAND()` repeats after 1 billion.)

Answer (score 1):

use a BEFORE INSERTTRIGGGER to generate UNIQUE numbers.

With `SET @NEW_ID = 1;` you define the first new value

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE table playerinventory ( id int PRIMARY KEY ,    amount INT , level int);
CREATE table newinventory ( id bigint PRIMARY KEY ,    amount INT , level int);

INSERT INTO playerinventory VALUEs (5,1,1),(6,2,2),(7,3,3),(8,4,4);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_newinventory_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON newinventory FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
    SELECT MAX(id) + 1
    INTO @NEW_ID
    FROM newinventory;
    IF @NEW_ID IS NULL THEN
        SET @NEW_ID = 1;
    END IF;
    set NEW.id = @NEw_ID;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO newinventory SELECT * FROM playerinventory;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM newinventory;

| id  | amount | level |
| --- | ------ | ----- |
| 1   | 1      | 1     |
| 2   | 2      | 2     |
| 3   | 3      | 3     |
| 4   | 4      | 4     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/17)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no one else is inserting into the table during this process, you can get a batch of available id:s like:

```
SELECT id+1
FROM newinventory x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM newinventory y
    WHERE y.id = x.id + 1
)
ORDER BY id+1
LIMIT 1000; -- batch size
```

Edit: The above will only get you next available id after each existing. If you have large gaps, you can use a recursive CTE to find all available id below a certain id:

```
with recursive T (n) as ( select 0 union all select n+1 from T where n+1 < 1000 )
select n from T
where not exists (
    select 1 from newinventory 
    where id = n
)
order by n
limit 100;
```

When you run out of available id:s, repeat the above. In the latter case you can initialize your base case with last found id:

```
with recursive T (n) as ( 
    select 1+@last_found 
    union all 
    select n+1 from T 
    where n+1 < 1000 + @last_found
)
select n from T
where not exists (
    select 1 from newinventory 
    where id = n
)
order by n
limit 100;
```